# Is there a divergent series with "largest" terms?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

> Suppose $a_n >0$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges. Define $$r_n = \sum_{k=n}^{\infty}a_k$$
>   Does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{r_n}$ diverge?

My thinking is yes. Could someone give hints/check?

Note that for all $m < n$, $r_m - r_{n+1} = a_m + ... + a_n$ so,

$$\frac{a_m}{r_m} + \frac{a_{m+1}}{r_{m+1}} + \cdots + \frac{a_n}{r_n} > \frac{a_m}{r_m} + \frac{a_{m+1}}{r_m} + \cdots + \frac{a_n}{r_m} > \frac{a_m}{r_m} + \frac{a_{m+1}}{r_m} + \cdots + \frac{a_n}{r_m} =\frac{r_m - r_{n+1}}{r_m} = 1 - \frac{r_{n+1}}{r_m}$$

A more interesting question is:

> Does there exist a $k$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{{\left(r_n \right)}^{\frac{1}{k}}}$ diverges?

My first guess would be to try and start with $k=2$ and seeing if that goes anywhere. Hints, ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a non-rigorous strategy, which I think can be made rigorous quite easily:
$$ \log(x) - \log (x-h) \approx \frac hx .$$
Hence
$$ \frac{a_n}{r_n} \approx \log(r_{n}) - \log(r_{n+1})  .$$
Hence, using a telescoping sum,
$$ \sum_{m=1}^n \frac{a_m}{r_m} \approx -\log(r_{n+1}) ,$$
which diverges since $r_{n+1} \to 0$.
Similarly, for every $k>1$,
$$ \sum_{m=1}^n \frac{a_m}{r_m^{1/k}} \approx \frac{k}{k-1}(r_1^{1-\frac1k}-r_{n+1}^{1-\frac1k})$$ which converges.

Comment: @Did Thank you for the edits.

Comment: You are welcome. Nice solution (much closer to a full proof than you pretend...).

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution to the second question based on a simple estimate from the mean value theorem which gives the bounds given by Stephen for the special case $1-\varepsilon=1/k$.

> Theorem: If $a_n>0$, $\sum_na_n<\infty$ and $r_n=\sum_{m\geq n}a_m$, then
> $$\sum_n\frac{a_n}{r^{1-\varepsilon}_n}<\infty$$
> for all $\varepsilon>0$.

Only the case $0<\varepsilon<1$ requires our attention. Notice that
\begin{align}
\frac{a_n}{r^{1-\varepsilon}_n}&=\frac{r_n-r_{n+1}}{r^{1-\varepsilon}_n}=\frac{(r^\varepsilon_n)^{1/\varepsilon}-(r^\varepsilon_{n+1})^{1/\varepsilon}}{r^{1-\varepsilon}_n}\\
&=\frac{1}{\varepsilon r^{1-\varepsilon}_n}\int^{r^\varepsilon_n}_{r^\varepsilon_{n+1}} t^{\frac{1}{\varepsilon}-1}\,dt\\
&\leq \frac1\varepsilon  (r^\varepsilon_n-r^\varepsilon_{n+1})
\end{align}

The telescopic series $$\sum_n(r^\varepsilon_n-r^\varepsilon_{n+1})=\Big(\sum^\infty_{n=1}a_n\Big)^{\varepsilon}<\infty$$
Hence,
$$\sum_n\frac{a_n}{r^{1-\varepsilon}_n}<\frac1\varepsilon r^\varepsilon_1=\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\Big(\sum_na_n\Big)^{\varepsilon}<\infty$$